# <error type="cancel" code="501"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/>

Tags: ios, xmpp, swift5, openfire, xmppframework

I am beginner in XMPP. I want to implement chat application with OpenFire server. I am able to make the proper connection with the server, but when I want to send any message to another Jabberid, I am receiving an error

```
SEND: <iq type="error" to="DOMAINMANE" id="348-5581"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:version"/><error type="cancel" code="501"><feature-not-implemented xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Here is the code,which I tried

```
extension AppDelegate{
private func setupStream() {
    //xmppRoster = XMPPRoster(rosterStorage: xmppRosterStorage)
    xmppRoster.activate(xmppStream)
    self.xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
    self.xmppRoster.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

}
func connect() -> Bool {
    if !xmppStream.isConnected {
        let jabberID = GlobleConstants.senderJID

        if !xmppStream.isDisconnected {
            return true
        }

        xmppStream.myJID = XMPPJID(string: jabberID)

        do {
            try xmppStream.connect(withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
            self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryReceipts = true
            self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.autoSendMessageDeliveryRequests = true
            self.xmppMessageDeliveryRecipts.activate(self.xmppStream)
            print("Connection success")
            return true
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong!")
            return false
        }
    } else {
        return true
    }

}
func disconnect() {
    goOffline()
    xmppStream.disconnect()
}
private func goOnline() {
    let presence = XMPPPresence()
    let domain = xmppStream.myJID?.domain

    if domain == GlobleConstants.XMPPHOSTNAME || domain == "gmail.com" || domain == "gtalk.com" || 
domain == "talk.google.com" {
        let priority = DDXMLElement.element(withName: "priority", stringValue: "24") as! DDXMLElement
        presence.addChild(priority)
    }
    xmppStream.send(presence)
}
private func goOffline() {
    let presence = XMPPPresence(type: "unavailable")
    xmppStream.send(presence)
}


}
extension AppDelegate : XMPPStreamDelegate{
func xmppStreamDidConnect(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
    do {
        try    xmppStream.authenticate(withPassword: GlobleConstants.sPassword)
    } catch {
        print("Could not authenticate")
    }
}
func xmppStreamDidAuthenticate(_ sender: XMPPStream) {
    goOnline()
}

func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive iq: XMPPIQ) -> Bool {
    print("Did receive IQ")
    return false
}


func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive message: XMPPMessage) {
    print("Did send message \(message)")
}
func xmppStream(_ sender: XMPPStream, didReceive presence: XMPPPresence) {
      print("IN APPDELEGATE -----> ", presence)
    let presenceType = presence.presenceType?.rawValue
          let myUsername = sender.myJID?.user
          let presenceFromUser = presence.from?.user
          print("MY USERNAME ",myUsername)
          print("OTHER USER NAME  ",presenceFromUser)
          print("PRESNET ",presenceType)
         **//HERE ALSO NOT GETTING ANOTHER ONLINE USER, SO THAT I CAN ADD INTO ONLINE BUDDIES LIST**
         /*if presenceFromUser != myUsername {
              print("Did receive presence from \(presenceFromUser)")
              if presenceType == "available" {
                  delegate.buddyWentOnline(name: "\(presenceFromUser)@\(GlobleConstants.XMPPHOSTNAME)")
              } else if presenceType == "unavailable" {
                  delegate.buddyWentOffline(name: "\(presenceFromUser)@\(GlobleConstants.XMPPHOSTNAME)")
              }
          }*/
}

}
extension AppDelegate : XMPPRosterDelegate{
    func xmppRoster(_ sender: XMPPRoster, didReceiveRosterItem item: DDXMLElement) {
        print("Did receive Roster item")
    }
}
```

And now inside of the controller, I am trying to fetch online buddies by

```
func setupUI(){
    appDelegate.delegate = self
    if appDelegate.connect() {
        self.title = appDelegate.xmppStream.myJID?.user
        appDelegate.xmppRoster.fetch()
    }
    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
```

But getting the same error. Anyone having solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting an error, you are *sending* one. After your client connects, Openfire queries it for its software version. Your client does not support that request, and sends back an error to Openfire ("feature not implemented"). This is perfectly reasonable, and no cause for concern.

If you want to get rid of the error, you can make your client respond to queries as defined in the protocol at https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0092.html